# Regular expression to remove page numbers in a document

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word, find, openoffice.org

I am trying to use either Microsoft Word or OpenOffice and regular expressions to remove page numbers in a document.  My file is an ebook that looks like

```
2
Words
More words.

More words.

More

3

words.
```

Some of the breaks are mid-sentence.  I tried to do this in Python but working with plain text files removes formatting such as italics which I am trying to keep.  In OpenOffice Writer, the regular expression:

```
^[0-9]$
```

will find any number between 0 and 9, although replacing 9 with 500 still only goes up to 9.  However, this only gets the number itself and not the paragraph breaks.  The regex

```
$
```

Can get the paragraph breaks but I'm not sure how to combine the two, or go beyond number 9.  Ultimately I just want to remove these page numbers and their paragraph breaks from the book.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: With ".. replacing 9 with 500" do you mean you attempted `[0-500]`? If that is the case, you'd better read up on regular expressions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `^[0-9]+$|$` for matching more digits and going beyond 9.

Comment: Awesome!  Is there anyway to include the preceding and subsequent paragraph breaks?  It is the $ symbol alone but I don't know how to combine them with ^[0-9]+$.

Comment: It says I can do it in 6 minutes and I surely will.  However, I don't think the edit changed it.  It's still only removing the number but not the preceding or subsequent paragraph break.  Any ideas :)?  Thanks so much either way!

Comment: So sorry, I'm a total newb, do you mean ^[0-9]+$^$?  That doesn't find anything.  Just plain ^$ finds a couple of unrelated instances but nothing near the relevant page numbers and breaks.

Comment: I dont think i got your scenario.. You have paragraphbreak-number-paragraphbreak.. and you want to remove these paragraphbreaks?

Comment: Wherever there is a linebreak-number-linebreak trio, I'd like to remove both the number (which your regex does already) as well as the two linebreaks.  I think they might technically be paragraph breaks as $ alone does work with them (but I only want to remove the linebreaks that are above and below the number).

Comment: try this: `\n\n^[0-9]+$\n\n` assuming `\n` is line break.. check this.. and you can also replace with `$` (i dont know because $ is just end of string and i am not able to check with $)

Comment: Hmm that didn't find anything.  I tried to do your original suggestion first, then after that worked replace ^[a-z] with nothing (i.e., if a lowercase letter starts a line the sentence is probably broken up).  That was able to find the mid-sentence splits, but the replace did nothing.  I also found another person saying OpenOffice can't replace over paragraph breaks which might explain it.  I'm guessing I might have to find another program.  If you know of any or have any other ideas that'd be great but if not you've been a saint and I completely appreciate you taking the time.  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :).  First get this extension: http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/alternative-dialog-find-replace-writer-altsearch.  Then use the regex
    \p^[0-9]+$\p